# Allow the users to upload profile images in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I already have a proper image upload system. It uploads & stores the image in the folder `/uploads/`, now I need to keep track of who uploads the profile image, and I want to display that image on my user profile page.

**This is my upload.php:**

```
<?php
include('db.php');

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
  header("location: error.php");    
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileError = $file['error'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                header("Location: user.php");
            } else {
                echo "Your file is too big!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
}
```

and this is the **HTML**:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="specialcontainer">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile">
</div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="uploadbuttonstyle">Upload</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I have 2 tables for this purpose, one handles the username, fname, lname, email, password, user description etc. And I want the second one to display the status of their profile image i.e if they have uploaded an image, status will be 1, if they haven't then status will be 0. And if status is 0, image from the directory `/uploads/profiledefault.jpg` will be displayed which is the default profile image for the new users. I'm still a beginner when it comes to PHP. Was hoping someone can show me the way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use another table for this. Just add one more column "profile_image" in your first table and save image in that table

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)) {
 // save/update "profile_image" field here.
}
```

and when you want to show profile image just check where profile_image column is blank or not. If it is then show default image "/uploads/profiledefault.jpg" else show profile image from the "profile_image" column.

Comment: Im guessing that I will have to use the UPDATE query to update the profile_image column and the WHERE clause will contain a unique value for each user such as his/her email?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have Entity named User. In this entity add property `profileImage` and save the path to the image after it is being uploaded. You get the current user and add the file path to his property `profileImage`. Each time a new user is registered you simply give `profileImage` the path to the default image `/uploads/profiledefault.jpg`. This means at every point the user will have profileImage and there is no need to check it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you figured out your answer but just in case you didn't I have some tips for you, IF YOU NEED A SCRIPT LRT ME KNOW.

When user logs in, get there Id in db by there username they inputed.

Then store that I'd in a session or cookie, session will be more secure, but cookie if it isn't in production yet.

Then call that cookie or session
And then use that cookie/session value to insert a specific users profile image, as if you make a script you can use those values to upload profile picture to a specific user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).